# Backing Up Kernel Modules from a GNU/Linux installation

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-module

How can I create a backup of all the driver modules (especially those that are not part of the original kernel yet) from an installation of GNU/Linux OS?

The original source of the proprietary drivers has gone offline and I need to do a clean install of another Gnu/Linux OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kernel modules are usually located in **/lib/modules**. You can create a backup by executing `tar -c -f backup.tar /lib/modules/$(uname -r)`. This will create(-c) a backup of the modules of your current kernel(uname -a) in the file(-f) backup.tar.
Note that kernel modules for one kernel version do not necessarily work with another kernel version.

A few modules come with firmware typically located in **/lib/firmware**. You can find out with `modinfo name_of_module`. You should see something like "firmware: xyz-123.ucode".

If you need to pass any options to the modules in **/etc/modprobe.d**, you have to backup that file as well. You can find out with `grep -r name_of_module /etc/modprobe.d`.

Comment: I was wondering if backing up the modules is all that's needed. Is there nothing else, eg. editing a few settings etc, that's needed?

Comment: That's all you need if you don't need to pass any options to the module. Updated answer with info about that.

Comment: a few modules have firmware typically in /lib/firmware

Comment: I have similar issue, but the modules also had dkms, specifically versions of NVIDIA Drivers, EVDI Display Link.

Are any other directories valuable in keeping a backup? 
I was thinking directories under /var/lib/dkms and /usr/src .